# Arguments not passed through file association

Tags: vbscript, registry, file-type, wsh

### Update

I edited `hkcr\vbsfile\shell` so it mirrors `hkcr\vbsfile\shell`. Arguments still don't work when using the filetype association for VBScript.

I wonder whether these registry keys make it fail:

```
:: reg query hkcr /f vbs*

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vbs
...
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBS
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBS Author
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBScript
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBScript Author
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBScript.Encode
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBScript.RegExp
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile.HostEncode
Suchvorgang abgeschlossen: 21 übereinstimmende Zeichenfolge(n) gefunden.
```

I cannot rename `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBS` or `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBScript`, not even when starting `regedit` as Administrator.

```
:: reg query hkcr\vbs /s

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vbs\CLSID
    (Standard)    REG_SZ    {B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vbs\OLEScript
    (Standard)    REG_NONE


:: reg query hkcr\vbscript /s

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vbscript
    (Standard)    REG_SZ    VB Script Language

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vbscript\CLSID
    (Standard)    REG_SZ    {B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vbscript\OLEScript
    (Standard)    REG_NONE


:: reg query hkcr\clsid\{B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8} /s

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\clsid\{B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}
    (Standard)    REG_SZ    VB Script Language

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\clsid\{B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}\
  Implemented Categories

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\clsid\{B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}\
  Implemented Categories\{F0B7A1A1-9847-11CF-8F20-00805F2CD064}
    (Standard)    REG_NONE    

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\clsid\{B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}\
  Implemented Categories\{F0B7A1A2-9847-11CF-8F20-00805F2CD064}
    (Standard)    REG_NONE    

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\clsid\{B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}\InprocServer32
    (Standard)    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vbscript.dll
    ThreadingModel    REG_SZ    Both

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\clsid\{B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}\OLEScript
    (Standard)    REG_NONE    

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\clsid\{B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}\ProgID
    (Standard)    REG_SZ    VBScript
```

### Original Post

Scripts do not receive arguments passed to them via the command line when invoked via the filetype association instead of via `cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe`.

```
:: type args.vbs
Option Explicit
WScript.Echo WScript.Arguments.Count
Dim arg
For Each arg In WScript.Arguments
        WScript.Echo arg
Next

:: cscript args.vbs eins zwei drei
3
eins
zwei
drei

:: wscript args.vbs eins zwei drei
:: : same thing via the MessageBox

:: args.vbs eins zwei drei
0

:: : Why is that?
:: assoc .vbs
.vbs=VBSFile

:: ftype VBSFile
VBSFile="%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*
```

It looks like this filetype association passes all arguments to the script. But maybe it isn't used? How can I track this down? Here's more info from the registry:

```
:: reg query hkcr\.vbs

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vbs
    (Standard)    REG_SZ    VBSFile

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vbs\PersistentHandler

:: reg query hkcr\VBSFile\Shell\Open /s

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open\Command
    (Standard)    REG_EXPAND_SZ    "%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*


:: reg query hkcr\VBSFile\Shell\Open2 /s

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open2
    (Standard)    REG_EXPAND_SZ    Open &with Command Prompt
    MUIVerb    REG_EXPAND_SZ    @%SystemRoot%\System32\wshext.dll,-4511

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open2\Command
    (Standard)    REG_EXPAND_SZ    "%SystemRoot%\System32\CScript.exe" "%1" %*
```

This is Windows 7 Pro 64, if it matters (which I don't think it does). One more thing, arguments work correctly in all three cases (`cscript.exe`, `wscript.exe`, filetype association) using the JScript engine with the following script:

```
var argc = WScript.Arguments.Length;
WScript.Echo(argc);
for (var i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        WScript.Echo( WScript.Arguments(i) );
```

Settings:

```
:: assoc .js
.js=JSFile

:: ftype JSFile
JSFile=C:\Windows\System32\WScript.exe "%1" %*

:: reg query hkcr\jsfile\shell\open\command

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jsfile\shell\open\command
    (Standard)    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\System32\WScript.exe "%1" %*


:: reg query hkcr\jsfile\shell\open2\command

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jsfile\shell\open2\command
    (Standard)    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\System32\CScript.exe "%1" %*
```

Comment: *"How can I track this down?"* Make it invalid and see if it still works. Alternatively, use Process Monitor and track registry usage directly. Also, what happens if you drag&drop a file onto the script in Explorer? Its path *should* be passed as an argument.

Comment: Great suggestion! I can drag a file onto `args.js` in Explorer, but not onto `args.vbs`. Changing the value of `hkcr\.vbs\{standard}`, script execution fails, of course ("Eingabefehler: Für die Dateierweiterung ".vbs" gibt es kein Skriptmodul.").

Comment: Tata! It works flawlessly when running `args.vbs` as `Administrator`! Guess I should be focussing on `HKCU` instead of `HKLM`!

Comment: Just for kicks, here is my machine's VBS registration. Maybe you find a difference? http://pastebin.com/M3iJTFUL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Searched the registry for `cscript`. There was the following key in my registry:

```
:: reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\cscript.exe /s
...
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\cscript.exe\shell\open\command
    (Standard)    REG_SZ    "C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe" "%1"
```

Once I fixed it to `"C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe" "%1" %*`, arguments started working correctly for VBScript using the file association. (Rest was okay anyway.)